# Why it doesn't popup multi definitions error for method in .h class for C++?

Tags: c++

There is one class.h object with method test() which has detailed execute content:

```
class Object{

  void test(){
    cout<<"do test"<<endl;
  }

}
```

Thus cpp1 include the Object.h and cpp2 includes it too.

Why it doesn't popup multiple definition error when linking cpp1 and cpp2?

Comment: Because it is implicitly inline.

Comment: Because the language specification says it shouldn't

Comment: @Keith, can you give some more detailed explain for it? 3ks

Comment: @jiafu: 3.2/4 (about the One definition Rule); "Every program shall contain exactly one definition of every **non-inline** function or variable that is odr-used
in that program; no diagnostic required". And 9.3./2: "A member function may be defined (8.4) in its class definition, in which case it is an **inline** member function
(7.1.2), [...]

Comment: See [here](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Finline_member.htm) for more info.